# ThinkingSphinx does not work in RSpec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, thinking-sphinx

I've read posts stating that this is due to transactional fixtures, but it looks like we're not using those. I've read other posts that suggest I do some funky stopping, restarting, and reindexing before each test run. That doesn't seem to help.

`ThinkingSphinx` runs just fine in the app, but in test it behaves very strangely. After creating a couple of `Organization` models in my spec, I run a sphinx search. It has the two records that I'm expecting, but also a lot of nils. That's annoying, but I add a `:retry_stale => true` and those go away, so I'm satisfied with this first query:

```
(rdb:1) p Organization.search '', :retry_stale => true
[#<Organization id: 1, ein: nil, name: "Allina", created_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", updated_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", parent_id: nil, main_phone: "7867685187x894", fax: nil, email: nil, url: nil, crm_id: 1, target_market: false, notes: nil, form990_notes: nil, mec_revenue: 750000.0, legacy_id: nil, teaching_program_type_id: nil, sponsorship_type_id: nil, is_member_council_teaching_hospitals: nil, has_teaching_program: nil, is_major_academic_medical_center: nil, does_participate_in_survey: nil, status: "modified", net_revenue: nil, gross_revenue: nil, source_name: nil, source_id: nil, import_concat_key: nil, bigtime_id: nil, is_non_hc: nil, is_client: nil, contact_record_id: nil, form990_legacy_id: nil, number_of_beds: nil, tax_exempt_status: nil, delta: true>, #<Organization id: 2, ein: nil, name: "HealthPartners", created_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", updated_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", parent_id: nil, main_phone: "3407862693x0935", fax: nil, email: nil, url: nil, crm_id: 1, target_market: false, notes: nil, form990_notes: nil, mec_revenue: nil, legacy_id: nil, teaching_program_type_id: nil, sponsorship_type_id: nil, is_member_council_teaching_hospitals: nil, has_teaching_program: nil, is_major_academic_medical_center: nil, does_participate_in_survey: nil, status: "modified", net_revenue: nil, gross_revenue: nil, source_name: nil, source_id: nil, import_concat_key: nil, bigtime_id: nil, is_non_hc: nil, is_client: nil, contact_record_id: nil, form990_legacy_id: nil, number_of_beds: nil, tax_exempt_status: nil, delta: true>]
```

But now if I try to search by name, which is most definitely indexed on my model, I don't get my record.

```
(rdb:1) p Organization.search 'Allina', :retry_stale => true
[]
```

I tried to modify the options to no avail, so I thought I'd just try searching for single letters in star mode. The results are disturbing.

```
(rdb:1) p Organization.search 'C', :star => true, :retry_stale => true
[#<Organization id: 1, ein: nil, name: "Allina", created_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", updated_at: "2012-09-11 15:03:04", parent_id: nil, main_phone: "7867685187x894", fax: nil, email: nil, url: nil, crm_id: 1, target_market: false, notes: nil, form990_notes: nil, mec_revenue: 750000.0, legacy_id: nil, teaching_program_type_id: nil, sponsorship_type_id: nil, is_member_council_teaching_hospitals: nil, has_teaching_program: nil, is_major_academic_medical_center: nil, does_participate_in_survey: nil, status: "modified", net_revenue: nil, gross_revenue: nil, source_name: nil, source_id: nil, import_concat_key: nil, bigtime_id: nil, is_non_hc: nil, is_client: nil, contact_record_id: nil, form990_legacy_id: nil, number_of_beds: nil, tax_exempt_status: nil, delta: true>]
```

There is clearly no letter 'C' in the `name` field. My model also indexes the `status` field, which is set to `modified`, and it indexes the `state` field of the `address` association. That value is 'CA', so I thought *maybe* `ThinkingSphinx` is finding that record with that index. So I thought I'd try to search for 'CA', and guess what happened:

```
(rdb:1) p Organization.search 'CA', :star => true, :retry_stale => true
[]
```

Nothing! What is with this wonky behavior? Ok, you guys probably want to see some configs and spec helpers and some index definitions:

## config/sphinx.yml

```
development:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1

test:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
```

## spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Spork.prefork do
  require 'headless'

  headless = Headless.new(:display => 99)
  headless.start
  at_exit do
    headless.destroy
  end

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'database_cleaner'

  #require 'rspec/autorun'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
    config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, :type => :request
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {
        :except => %w(sponsorship_types teaching_program_types title_groups positions tax_exempt_organization_types)}
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
end
```

## app/models/organization.rb

```
  define_index do
    indexes :name, :sortable => true
    indexes address(:state), :as => :state
    indexes status

    set_property :delta => true
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We wrote Thinking Spec tests in Test Unit. It worked pretty well.
Include the following in your spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'thinking_sphinx/test'
ThinkingSphinx::Test.init
```

Also, in each test, have ThinkingSphinx::Test.start in the setup and ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop in the teardown

Comment: Thanks, it turns out some rake tasks are indeed in order. It looks like I also have to run a `rake ts:index RAILS_ENV=test` every time I clean the DB and load new data.